# TableView commitEditing method

Tags: objective-c, tableview, editing

I got a tableview which is the one by default when you create a tableview using core data application, and there is this fetching managed object I don't really understand, anyway when the user delete something from the tableview i need to take the object that is deleted and gets it as a String, it is possible?

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
 [context deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

This is where the object is deleted, I need to know what item has been deleted in a
string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]` refers to the object that is being deleted (since it's being passed to `deleteObject:`). Unfortunately, I can't help you any farther than that, because I can't be sure how you want to create a string from the object.

But I can *guess* that you probably wish to access some string attribute of the object (perhaps a name or ID?) To do this you can use `valueForKey:`. So, to create, for example, a string out of the deleted object's name (assuming, of course, that the object *has* an attribute called "name"), you could use:

```
[[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"name"]
```

Comment: ok thx but when i use what you said, it gave me the good object but with some non-understandable things. Like this : my object is supose to be  Beer 5% 5oz for exemple and it gave me : Beer 222042722134z